# Automatic correction of Java Calendar day of month?

Tags: java, calendar

I want to learn that is there any easiest way to correct the values of day when setting it. I mean:

```
int birthDay = 30;
int birthMonth = 1;
int birthYear = 1980;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, birthDay);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, birthMonth);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, birthYear);
```

February doesn't have the day of 30. On the other hand it has a special condition, 1980 is a year that February is 29 days. So I have to get the corrected value as "1980-February-29". It should take the maximum day of that month if I exceed the range of month. How can I do it at simplest way and if I can find solution that doesn't need to write any extra code instead of using the methods of Calendar class it will be perfect.

**EDIT:** I changed cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, birthMonth-1); to cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, birthMonth); sorry for it.

Comment: Calendar correctly processes heap years. So no need in PS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, birthYear);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, birthMonth);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Math.min(birthDay, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) to find the maximum day of the month

Answer (score 0):

No, currently it's the only way.

Of course, you might want to parse a date from a String using a `java.text.DateFormat` object (typically a `SimpleDateFormat`). This is the most close to a one-liner you can get if your input is a `String`.

Comment: Please note that with the upcoming Java 7, things will probably change, since a whole new API will be available.